# Meaning of energy eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator

I have this question which I'm trying to solve:

> Consider a particle with harmonic oscillator potential at $t=0$; which has the initial state
> $$ |\psi (0)\rangle = \frac{1}{2}|E_0\rangle + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}|E_2\rangle$$
> Find $|\psi (t)\rangle$, $\langle \psi(t)|x^2|\psi(t)\rangle$ and the frequency of oscillations of the above expectation value.

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly the $E_0$ and $E_2$ states represent, how they link with the wavefunctions and how to proceed in general.

P.S: I am supposed to stay within Dirac notations for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your wave function is a linear combination of the ground state and the second excited state. As time progresses the wave function changes by Schrodinger equation.

For harmonic oscillator
$ E_n  = (n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar \omega$

Wavefunction at time t can be found by

$\vert \psi_n (t)\rangle=\vert \psi_n(0) \rangle e^{-i\frac{E_n t}{\hbar}}$ using these wavefunction at later time can be found out.

For finding expectation value of position x can be taken as, x= $\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}} (a+a^+)$

Take its square, act on the wave function you are good to go.

If I were setting this question I will give the wavefunction as

$\vert \psi(0) \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\vert \psi_0 \rangle +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \vert \psi_2 \rangle$ now you will understand one of the wavefunction is in ground state and other is in second excited state. By convention we use $\psi$ for wavefunction and not E, I think that's what caused your confusion.

Answer (score 3):

$|E_n \rangle $ stands for the energy eigenstate $n$, also often written simply  as $|n\rangle$.  These states satisfy by definition the time indendent Schrödinger equation
$$
\hat H|n\rangle  = E_n |n\rangle,
$$
where $E_n$ is the energy eigenvalue.

You are given a state at timepoint $t_0=0$ in terms of a linear combination of energy eigenstates,
$$
|\psi(t=0)\rangle =\frac{1}{2}|0 \rangle + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}|2\rangle 
$$
The time dependency of an energy eigenstate is trivial and simply given by
$$
|n(t)\rangle   = e^{-iE_nt/\hbar }|n \rangle 
$$
This means that your time dependent state is simply
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = \frac{1}{2}e^{-iE_0t/\hbar }|0 \rangle + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}e^{-iE_2t/\hbar }|2\rangle 
$$
To do the calculation for the harmonic oscillator you have to insert the eigenvalues and eigenstates of the harmonic oscillator.

The next step is to decide on a basis to do  the calculation of the expectation  value $\langle \psi(t)|\hat x^2|\psi(t)\rangle$. In the case of the harmonic oscillator you can  calculate the expectation value using the energy eigenstate representation and ladder operators, alternatively you can use the position representation. Ladder operators are simpler if you are familiar with them and require simple algebra to calculate the expectation value while the position representation turns the problem to an integral.

Since this sounds like homework i'll leave the calculation to you.